# What is the operation used to transform this expression into this one

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to find $u$ and $v$ so that $600u + 124v = \gcd(600,124) = 4$.

I completely understand the algorithm to find the gcd, but then, to find the coefficients, I don't understand what operation is done between the two lines (with the blue arrow), how do we get from $104-(124-104\times1)\times5$ to $124\times(-5)+104\times6$ ?

Thank you
[image]

Comment: If you just expand the brackets without multiplying the numbers themselves, you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

$$  \gcd( 600, 124 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 600 }{ 124 } = 4 +  \frac{ 104 }{ 124 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 124 }{ 104 } = 1 +  \frac{ 20 }{ 104 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 104 }{ 20 } = 5 +  \frac{ 4 }{ 20 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 20 }{ 4 } = 5 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 4 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 & & 4 & & 1 & & 5 & & 5 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 4 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 5 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 29 }{ 6 }   & &   \frac{ 150 }{ 31 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{ccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 4 }{ 1 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 5 }{ 1 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  5  \\  
  \frac{ 29 }{ 6 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  5  \\  
  \frac{ 150 }{ 31 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  0  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 150 \cdot 6 - 31 \cdot 29 = 1 $$

$$  \gcd( 600, 124 ) = 4  $$
 $$ 600 \cdot 6 - 124 \cdot 29 = 4 $$